I have question regarding marriage
What if wife refuses to return to her husband after staying in inlaws house for sometime and going to visit maika..And the father of girl is not willing to send his daughter back?
Is'nt it equivalent to saying wife abandoned the husband?
What do smritis say in this case?

What is the reason for not coming back or his father not sending her back?

I dont know the reason
